# Delete row using Color from the Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, colors

I am trying to delete values in a column that have certain dates. I came up with this code using conditional formatting to turn certain cells a certain color, and then loop through again and delete the cells that are that certain color.

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteRows14()
Dim xrow As Long, xcol As Long, rcell As Range

xrow = 1
xcol = 2

Do Until Cells(xrow, xcol).Value = ""
    Cells(xrow, xcol).Select
    If Cells(xrow, xcol).Value <> "" Then
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="**/**/14", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
            .Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        If Cells(xrow, xcol).Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then
            Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        End If

    End If
    xrow = xrow + 1
Loop
```

That second If statement `If Cells(xrow, xcol).Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then` won't register as true. I can't get any rows to delete.

This is where I'm at now.

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteRows14()
Dim xrow As Long, xcol As Long, rcell As Range

xrow = 1
xcol = 2

Do Until Cells(xrow, xcol).Value = ""
    Cells(xrow, xcol).Select
    If Cells(xrow, xcol).Value <> "" Then
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="**/**/14", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
        If Application.Evaluate(Selection.FormatConditions(1).Formula1) Then
            Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        Else: xrow = xrow + 1

        End If

    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Why 2 step process when you can directly delete the row? Also note that if you delete a row and also increment the variable `xrow` you might miss a row in between.